# Is a Dell XPS 15 L502x with three 24" monitors (1920 x 1200) possible?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, cpu-usage

I'm at a crossroads and need some PC advice. I'm a web developer so I'll have a few local web and DB servers running, maybe Photoshop and or Illustrator, any number of MS Office programs running, SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio. Occasionally, ill game but nothing like 13 hour CS sessions that I used to put in.

I have a Dell XPS 15 L502x:

- [Intel Core i7-2630QM @ 2.00GHz](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i7-2630QM%20@%202.00GHz&id=873)
- [NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-540M.41715.0.html)
- [Corsair Vengeance 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 1600 MHz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0076W9Q5A)

It's definitely enough power for everything I do. No question about that. However, last week I was working at a clients office. They had a developer out on vacation so I ended up using his PC that was hooked up to a triple monitor array of awesomeness!

Now that I have been exposed to the triple. I gotta have it. I saw that there are some external adapters on Amazon that could accommodate my PC running 3 external monitors but I'm pretty suspect about trying to support 2 x 24''monitors (1920x1200) with my CPU and one with my GPU. I'll spend the G on the triple setup but I'm afraid of the lag / performance loss.

Hopefully you guys can help me with this.

1. Will running 3 monitors with my current setup using external adapters noticeably slow down performance?
2. Does a real external GPU exist? Or are they all CPU driven adapters?
3. Do I just need a new rig to support three 24" monitors 1920 x 1200?

**More info:**

---

[image: Windows Experience Index]

Comment: Stay away from USB2.0 VGA adapters. They are horrible. The experience is like being RDP'd into the desktop. Everything is laggy and slow. You're best bet may be to get a USB3 VGA or DVI adapter and a USB3 Hub. If you do go this route, make sure that you get a powered hub.

Comment: Will this adapter use the CPU?

Comment: Was this setup powered by a laptop?  The most I ever see powered by a laptop is dual monitor via docking station.

Comment: @Ramhound I have a MSI GS70 that supports 3 external monitors as well as the primary laptop screen. In total, I have 4 monitors rocking on my development lappy.

Comment: Picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nxwxx.png Lappy: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834152443

Comment: Here is the adapter that I've read the best reviews on. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA2XB1278870 You do need to be careful with cheaper ones as they seem to have lots of issues. As far as CPU load, I couldn't really tell you how much of a performance hit it would take.

Comment: @kobaltz what adapters do you use?

Comment: I don't use any. My lappy supports three monitors out of the box. My desktop supports 6 monitors. I have no need for the adapter unless I want to add more to the laptop (which the boss won't approve).

Comment: I use 3 monitors on my i5 based Lenovo. One from the docking stations VGA port, 1 from the Mini Display Port on the laptop, 1 from a Lenovo USB 2 external dock (VGA). Works really well although you do get some jitter when dragging large windows occasionally. Just don't expect too much from the USB connected monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound Call MSI and Newegg and tell them you deserve some swag... I just bought your rig.